# Getting Compile error in case of Switch statement with ENUM and FINAL variable?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, final

I am facing a weird issue.

I have a Static Final variable declared but not initialized.
I have a private method xyz() inside which I am having a Switch statement.

But I am betting a compile time error : "The final field ABC cannot be assigned" - "Remove the final modifier of ABC".

P.S. The switch case is checking on a value returned from ENUM

Kindly help me out.

Here is the code:-

```
private static final String ABC;
private void xyz(){
switch(ENUMImpl.getCountry()){         //** ENUMImpl is an ENUM class with a method getCountry() which returns the ENUM value

case COUNTRY1:
        ABC = "TMZ"; // The final field ABC cannot be assigned :: Remove final modifier of ABC
        break;
default:
        ABC = "NA";
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: `final` fields can only be assigned directly or withing a static initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field is **`static`** and **`final`**.

This means that the field is at the `Class` level, not the instance level. And the field must be assigned once - in the case of a `static` field it much be assigned during `Class` initialisation.

There is nothing to stop you doing:

```
public MyClass() {
    xyz();
    xyz();
}
```

i.e. calling `xyz` twice in the constructor, so that it attempts to assign `ABC` for each instance. This obviously makes `ABC` not `static final` - nor it is instance `final` as it is assigned twice.

What's worse, you could call `zyx()` from arbitrary instance methods.

You have to ensure that `ABC` is only every assigned once per `Class` instance, i.e. when the `ClassLoader` loads the `class`.

You need to do something like:

```
private static String xyz(){
    switch(ENUMImpl.getCountry()) {
        case COUNTRY1:
            return "TMZ";
        default:
            return "NA";
    }
}

static {
    ABC = xyz();
}
```

Note:

1. Your formatting is very ugly, please use auto format in your IDE before posting.
2. `ENUMImpl` is a **terrible** name for anything. It is obviously an `enum` as it it declared as such and it it obviously an implementation otherwise it wouldn't exist. So this tells you absolutely nothing about its purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Yes, I have just started using stackoverflow; so I will keep all your suggestions in mind while posting the next time.

Comment: @anirbandebnath those are suggestions for your coding in general. If one of my developers came up with `ENUMImpl` they would have to read [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) again, from cover to cover.

Comment: @anirbandebnath also, if this answered your question, don't forget to [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).